# Send a Post request with the current excel sheet as multi-part form data using vba

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I'm trying to send the current working excel sheet to an api accepting Content-type: "multipart-form".
I need help to form the request in vba.
Following is my approach:

```
Sub sendInternalDataToAPI(myCSVFileName As String)
    Dim data As Worksheet
    Dim boundary As String
    Dim filename As String


    boundary = "--------------------------784780577729000449617522"
    filename = "data"
    Set data = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
    'Set payload = preparePayload(data)
    Url = "http://localhost:8080/load"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    With objHTTP
    .Open "POST", Url, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" & boundary
    .send (preparePayload(data, boundary, myCSVFileName))
    strResponseStatus = .StatusText
    strResponse = .ResponseText
    allResponseHeader = .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With
    Debug.Print strResponseStatus
    Debug.Print allResponseHeader
    Debug.Print strResponse
End Sub

Function preparePayload(data As Worksheet, boundary As String, filename As String) As String

    Debug.Print boundary & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""data""; filename=""" & filename & """" & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" & vbCrLf & _
    data & vbCrLf & _
    boundary & "--"

    preparePayload = boundary & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""data""; filename=""" & filename & """" & vbCrLf & _
    "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" & vbCrLf & _
     data & vbCrLf & _
     boundary & "--"
End Function
```

On Executing I get the following error:

> VBA Error: 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

The variable "data" in the form body is causing the error. I'm not sure what am I missing!
And, I got the Content-type in request-body from postman, which is executing fine!
I'm quite new in vba, any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
The postman request from the postman console is:

```
Request ---
POST <url>/load HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.22.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d3a4355f-548a-4b10-b8b7-53c62772cc4a
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------360126624207643168890089
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Length: 352982
Connection: keep-alive
----------------------------360126624207643168890089
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="test-excel.xlsx"

<test-excel.xlsx>
----------------------------360126624207643168890089--


Response---

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 13:41:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

response Body fromt the server--
{"data":true}
```

*How is this working with only the file name  in the request body and not the contents??*

Comment: You need to explain a bit more about exactly what type of content the API expects.  If it's looking for an Excel workbook as a file upload, you first need to make sure you've saved that sheet to a file on disk, and then loaded it into your request object.  Previously on this topic:  https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+post+excel+file+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: The api is expecting a multipart/form-data, with payload data:<file>According to the solution in the link, I need to convert the sheet(data) into binary and then post it as a payload, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Okay, now I've read the file into buffer and converted to string and passed in the payload as mentioned in the link. Now I'm getting this error from the server: ```Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Buffer size exceeded: no line terminator```   Is the StrConv function somehow messing up the file size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got it done!

As @TimWilliams mention in the comments, basically I had to:
1. save the file first from excel 
2. read it back to excel as String 
3. Convert to Bytes and then send it via http

Also this post helped dearly: [google.com/search?q=vba+post+excel+file+site:stackoverflow.com](http://google.com/search?q=vba%20post%20excel%20file%20site:stackoverflow.com)

Also, if there was a way to send the ActiveWorkbook.sheet("MY_SHEET") directly to the api, that would have been really nice.
Will keep exploring!

Thanks @TimWilliams!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to "convert" the **Worksheet** variable "data" into a **String** in your **preparePayload function**.

I'm not sure what you need to "prepare" for the API you're using, if it's the name of the Worksheet itself you can get it by using the .Name method, if it's something else you need to make sure to properly convert it to a String, or make sure it can be implicitly converted.

Comment: Well its the worksheet itself that I was trying to send as a payload, without opening it explicitly from the disk.